# Swapping an image via jquery when using an image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, imagemap

I am trying to build a image map link that swaps the image out for another image. The idea is that the user can click on a small defined area (that would say "click here") and the image will swap to a second image. The second image will have a small area that says "previous" so clicking the same area will make the image return to the original one.

This is as far as I got, so far no image changes, however it seems like the image map is working.

Can anyone figure out how to get this working correctly?

**html:**

```
<div id="picture_here">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo11w.png" id="picture"  usemap="#imageMap"/>
</div>

<map name="imageMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100"  href="JavaScript: test(); void(0);">
</map>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var swapImage = 1;


function test(){
        if (swapImage == 1){
            swapImage = 2;
            $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://s1.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_frontpage_en-AU_s_f_p_bestfit_frontpage_2x.png');
        }else if (swapImage == 2){
            swapImage = 1;
            $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
        }
}
```

See [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rhess/35/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it works. In jsfiddle, you are getting js error because test function not found in js fiddle. If you put js code in `script` tag in html section like below, you can see it is working.

```
<div id="picture_here">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo11w.png" id="picture"  usemap="#imageMap"/>
</div>

<map name="imageMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100"  href="JavaScript: test(); void(0);">
</map>
    <script>
    var swapImage = 1;


function test(){
        if (swapImage == 1){
            swapImage = 2;
            $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://s1.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_frontpage_en-AU_s_f_p_bestfit_frontpage_2x.png');
        }else if (swapImage == 2){
            swapImage = 1;
            $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
        }
}    
    </script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhess/36/)**

Alternativelly, you can use "No wrap - in " config in jsfiddle. You can see demo for that

**[Demo No Wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/rhess/38/)**

Answer (score 2):

The example you have should work, the only problem you have here are the settigns in jsfiddle.

You should use "No wrap - in < head >" instead of "onLoad"

The difference  is that onLoad will execute your script after the page loads and you won't have a way to call your function test().

With "No wrap - in < head >" is like adding your javascript source on the head of the document and will let you call function from the html.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a click handler rather than inline JavaScript. The problem is that your test function cannot be found.

```js
var swapImage = 1;


$('area').on('click', function() {
        if (swapImage == 1){
            swapImage = 2;
            $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://s1.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_frontpage_en-AU_s_f_p_bestfit_frontpage_2x.png');
        }else if (swapImage == 2){
            swapImage = 1;
            $('#picture').attr('src', 'https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
        }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhess/37/

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want ;-)

[example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/velamucefoju/1/)